# Accessing a variable global structure from within an array

Tags: c, function, variables, pointers

I have a function that will be used to pull data from different global structures. So, I'm trying to pass a char array into the function that tells the function which global structure to pull from (via naming it). However, I'm having trouble getting it to work as intended! (I am a beginner at C).

Example code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

// linear interpolation
float linearInterp(int userTime, char* structure[], char* array[])
{
    printf("%d", structure[1].array);
} // end float linearInterp()

struct heartRate
{
    int time;
    int beats;
    char units[8];
} HR[50];


int main()
{
    float val1;
    HR[1].beats = 2300;
    char beating[6] = "beats";
    char *p = beating;
    char hring[3] = "HR";
    char *ph = hring;

    val1 = linearInterp(5, beating, hring); // note: attempted with both p and ph vs beating and hring
} // end int main()
```

The code as it is simply gives the error: "request for member 'array' in something not a structure or union.

Ideally, my code would return the value assigned to HR[1].beats in the main function, 2300.

I believe there may be something wrong with my line of thinking, trying to use a string variable in c as the name of an array. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in C to retrieve a variable given its name in a `char *`.

There is no way in C to retrieve a field value of a structure variable given the field name in a `char *`.

C is not JavaScript.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks. Didn't know it wouldn't work that way. I think I'll just use numbers and cases probably, then.